# How to use multiple form in for..each in TYPO3 Extbase Extension

Tags: typo3, fluid, extbase, typo3-extensions, typo3-9.x

I'm using TYPO3 9.5.4 and want do create multiple forms on one page.

What I did looks like this:

```
    <f:for each="{artikels}" as="artikel" iteration="i">
        <f:form action="create" name="newPreisliste{i.cycle}" object="{newPreisliste{i.cycle}}">
            .......
        </f:form>
    </f:for>
```

But I get the following error:

```
(1/1) #1320830018 TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Security\Exception\InvalidHashException
The given string was not appended with a valid HMAC.
```

Is there a way to solve that or am I fighting windmills? : )

Comment: Just for the record, multiple forms that submit multiple objects may not be a good design decision if you name the objects thusly - since the form object name and the controller action are tied together and the controller action does not by default support arbitrary arguments. It also hints that you are in the process of writing a controller that breaks the normal Extbase design patterns and reads arguments in a non-standard and non-validated way - which if true, you definitely should reconsider.

Comment: Yeah, guess I've to.

Comment: I've stripped down the complete form to just the submit button for testing purpose and I still get the error message. I've learned that this might be due to form manipulation, but I don't do that. That gives me such a headache.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a (previously unreported) variant of the problem solved by https://github.com/TYPO3/Fluid/pull/419 which is included in version 2.6.0 of Fluid. If you are using composer you can update that package separately by calling `composer update typo3fluid/fluid` - if you do not use a composer based installation you must either patch the files manually, or await the next release of TYPO3 which should bump and export the new version as included library.

Comment: Thank's for coming back on this. I've updated to the latest github version but still get the same error message. It's either not solving the problem or it's just not ment to work this way. I may have to reconsider the design.